# tracing services to packages

Tags: package-management, services

Hello I want to programmatically trace a service back to its software package. Is there a command that would allow me to determine which package(s) support a service?

Thanks!

Comment: I was thinking search systemd unit files for services. And look at the file in the execPath directive. And then determine which package is associated with that file...

Comment: You can just check which package created the unit file directly.